# TypeScript compiler is not guessing variable type in if statement

Tags: typescript, if-statement, compiler-errors

I am currently working on this question called '[Merge Two Binary Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-binary-trees/description/)' from leetcode.

I'm solving this problem with TypeScript and my solution passes tests just fine but the compiler is showing an error like this.

[image]

What I don't understand is, I clearly covered every case and TS should be guessing that root2 can't be null at the point where it's yelling 'root2 is possibly null'.

Am I missing any case or it's just me not understanding how the compiler behave..?

It would be much appreciated if you could point me in the right direction.

**My solution**

```
const mergeTrees = (
  root1: TreeNode | null,
  root2: TreeNode | null
): TreeNode | null => {
  if (!root1 && !root2) return null;
  if (root1 && root2)
    return new TreeNode(
      root1.val + root2.val,
      mergeTrees(root1.left, root2.left),
      mergeTrees(root1.right, root2.right)
    );
  if (root1 && !root2)
    return new TreeNode(
      root1.val,
      mergeTrees(root1.left, null),
      mergeTrees(root1.right, null)
    );
  return new TreeNode(
    root2.val,
    mergeTrees(null, root2.left),
    mergeTrees(null, root2.right)
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't think TS is capable of deducing what you expect it to. Doesn't really work with conditions that depend on multiple variables. You can just tell it that you're sure the variable will be defined at that point with `root2!.val`

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are limits to the flow analysis that TypeScript's compiler does. Although *you* (and we) know from the code logic that `root2` can't be `null` there at the end, TypeScript doesn't.

You have at least three options:

1. Use a non-nullish type assertion on `root2`
2. Write an explicit test that throws an assertion error if `root2` is `null`, inline in that function
3. Use a type assertion function

### Use a non-nullish type assertion

The [`!` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) at the end of a value expression is an assertion saying "I know this value will never be `null` or `undefined` ('nullish')." So you could use it in all three places:

```typescript
return new TreeNode(
    root2!.val,
    mergeTrees(null, root2!.left),
    mergeTrees(null, root2!.right)
);
```

or in just one place, by assigning to a new identifier:

```typescript
const r = root2!;
return new TreeNode(
    r.val,
    mergeTrees(null, r.left),
    mergeTrees(null, r.right)
);
```

Like all type assertions, if you get your logic wrong, TypeScript won't be able to help you because it will believe what you tell it. So if the logic is wrong, you'll get an unexpected error accessing `root2` when it's nullish.

### Explicit inline test of `root2`

You could also add a runtime check and throw an assertion error:

```typescript
if (!root2) {
    throw new Error("Assertion failure, 'root2' can't be nullish here");
}
return new TreeNode(
    root2.val,
    mergeTrees(null, root2.left),
    mergeTrees(null, root2.right)
);
```

That has the advantage of **both** testing your assertion and providing a clear error about it, and reassuring TypeScript's compiler.

### A type assertion function

This is pretty much the same as above, but in a reusable package. You can write a reusable [type assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) that tests for nullish values and throws the error:

```typescript
// In some utilities module...
function assertIsNotNullish<T>(value: T | null | undefined): asserts value is T {
    if (value === null || value === undefined) {
        throw new Error("Value shouldn't be nullish here");
    }
}

// In your mergeTrees function:
assertIsNotNullish(root2);
return new TreeNode(
    root2.val,
    mergeTrees(null, root2.left),
    mergeTrees(null, root2.right)
);
```

This has the same advantage that it **both** tests the assertion and also reassures the compiler.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer!

> There are limits to the flow analysis that TypeScript's compiler does. Although you (and we) know from the code logic that root2 can't be null there at the end, TypeScript doesn't.

Ah! Right so it's something beyond the complier's capability. For this one I'm certain that root2 can't be null so I will go with non-nullish type assertion.
Again thank you so much for the help:)

Answer (score 2):

You could shorten your code with [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) and ternaries, which should also allow the compiler to resolve types

```
const mergeTrees = (
  root1: TreeNode | null,
  root2: TreeNode | null
): TreeNode | null => {
  if (!root1 && !root2) return null;
  else {
    return new TreeNode(
      (root1.val ?? 0) + (root2.val ?? 0),
      mergeTrees(root1 ? root1.left : null, root2 ? root2.left : null),
      mergeTrees(root1 ? root1.right : null, root2 ? root2.right : null)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: They should use `undefined` instead because then you could use `root1?.left`. I mean, you could use `root?.left ?? null` but that's just silly...

Comment: Thank you so much! I did use nullish coalescing for the initial answer but I got rid of it since the code is not working the way I intended. But hey this is working perfectly in combination with ternaries!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with typescript, but I can help in the right direction:
In C# there's a case where you can have nullable variables and non-nullable variables. and usually before you're able to use these nullable variables, you have to make them non-nullable instead.

As example in C#:

```
DateTime? date = null //nullable variable 
int seconds = 0;

date = DateTime.Now();

if (date != null)
{
    //it's ensured that date is not null, but this still won't compile, 
    //because it's still a nullable variable
    seconds = date.Second;

    //instead, it should be converted to a non-nullable variable. In C#, this goes with '.Value'.
    seconds = date.Value.Second;
}
```